# Forcing inlining of callback (lambda) in C++17 in library

Tags: c++, lambda, inlining

I'm building a runtime system that allows a programmer to specify a callback that is invoked at particular points. I'm using clang 7.0.1 / `-std=c++17`. The callback is registered in the runtime by storing a lambda as a `std::function`. When the runtime later calls the `std::function` callback, it passes 6 arguments (a necessity given the generality of the runtime). Note that the `std::function` is being created in an application but is used by a statically-linked library, which is compiled separately. However, I'm using LTO (via `-flto` and LLD 7.0.1) so I was hoping it would be able to still do this optimization. I'm new to some of this stuff so hopefully this is possible.

When I compile with `-O3` and specify `__attribute__((flatten))` on the calling function declaration, the lambda is not inlined. I can see when I run my system using perf events that the function isn't being inlined:

```
return _M_invoker(_M_functor, std::forward<_ArgTypes>(__args)...);
 mov    -0x90(%rbp),%rdi  
 lea    -0x48(%rbp),%rsi  
 mov    %rbx,%rdx         
 mov    %r15,%rbx         
 callq  *0x180(%r15)      
...
```

This call is taking a non-trivial amount of time and it seems like something that should be inlinable; there are only a few callsites in total. I've certainly seen lambdas inlined before but I'm not sure if my approach of using a functor (via `std::function`) somehow disqualifies inlining.

Is forcing an inline possible? Let me know if more info is needed here.

**EDIT:**
Thanks for all of the very useful information. I realize now that the way I've set up my runtime, it's not giving the compiler a chance to inline the callback. The comments make it clear why that is the case. There were some allusions to alternative approaches that may be inlinable. Given that 1) I'm in control of both the application and runtime source (and programming models / APIs); 2) I'm compiling both the library and application at once (and can even make them a unified build process), are there alternative approaches that I could take here that would potentially allow an inline to occur? Maybe templates and lambdas (not `std::functions`)? I'm new to this area and am all ears if anyone has ideas on how to effectively give the compiler what it needs to inline. Worst case scenario, I can even build a custom version of the library (as a proof of concept) for each application if that opens up any possibilities...

Comment: "*it seems like something that should be inlinable*" How do you figure? Your description strongly suggests that the point of definition of the lambda and the point of the eventual call of a `std::function` object that just so happens to contain that lambda are very far apart (as in, in different translation units). So why would you expect inlining? Link-time optimization is not magic; it can only do so much.

Comment: Have you even measured if that's your bottleneck?

Comment: The only way for a compiler to make a registered callback inlineable is to prove that it's the only callback that will ever be registered. LTO cannot normally do that. It is not a whole-program optimisation technology.

Comment: @Swordfish I see using perf record -e cycles:pp that initializing and calling the functor is in my critical path and one of the top three things I can optimize right now

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of `std::function` is to have a common type that can hold an arbitrary callable for a certain signature while, at the same time, allowing that arbitrary callable to be invoked through a common interface no matter what kind of thing the callable actually happened to be. Thus, if you think about it, `std::function` inherently requires an indirection of some sort. Which code needs to run for calling an `std::function` depends not just on the type, but on the particular value of the `std::function`. This makes `std::function` (at least the call to the stored callable) inherently not inlineable. The code generated for the function calling your callback has to be able to handle any `std::function` you may possibly throw at it. The only way a compiler could potentially offer something like inlining for `std::function` would be if it was somehow able to figure out that your function calling the callback is most of the time only going to be used with `std::function` objects holding a particular value and then generate a clone of the function calling the callback for that specific case. This would either require an almost unrealistically clairvoyant compiler to arrive at in general, or a lot of magic hardwired into the compiler just for `std::function` specifically. It's not completely impossible in theory. But I've never witnessed any compiler actually being able to do anything like that. In my experience, optimizers are just not really able to see through `std::function`. And I would not expect that to change anytime soon, as getting any meaningful optimization there would seem to require huge amounts of effort for a rather questionable benefit. `std::function` is just heavy machinery to begin with. You simply pay for what you use there. If you can't pay the price, don't use `std::function`…

Comment: std::function is hardly relevant here. It's extremely unlilely to be inlineable with plain old function pointers either. Indirection is inherent in a registerable callback system.

Comment: @n.m. I have to disagree on `std::function` being hardly relevant here. The question is specifically asking about `std::function`. While what you say about calling the callable in an `std::function` being similar to just calling a function through a plain function pointer is absolutely correct, I think this is not necessarily obvious to everyone. At least, given how many times I've recently seen examples on this site alone of people using `std::function` to pass lambdas to function templates just for them to be called right away, I have to conclude that this is apparently anything but obvious…

Comment: …I'm under the impression that there must be some misguided but, unfortunately, popular source out there that's teaching `std::function` as the default way of passing lambdas around…

Comment: *std::function as the default way of passing lambdas around* Nothing wrong with that really. Unless you are writing a template of course.

Comment: @n.m. Exactly. Yet I've seen just variations of the question of how to get the template arguments for an `std::function` deduced from a lambda argument so that a given template may call the lambda so many times over the past month that I'm losing count…for some reason, it seems people think of `std::function` as a magic lambda container rather than a polymorphic function object…

Comment: the question is very simple. Would a function pointer be optimised away in this situation? If I understand OP's intent correctly, it would not. Hence removing additional layers of indirection that std::function may impose will do nothing.

Comment: @n.m. sure, but I'm not convinced that's something that's automatically obvious to everyone…I'd consider the very existence of this question here evidence of that…

Comment: A smart compiler could in theory optimise away std::function whenever a plain function would be inlineable. I don't know any that actually does but there's no real advanced magic about it. The technology exists and I expect it to be used in the near future.